# Does serverless framework supports Lambda canary deployment (Alias Traffic Shifting )?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

Does serverless framework support canary deployment by switching weights on Lambda alias (like SAM/CodeDeploy: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-canary-deployments-of-aws-lambda-functions-with-alias-traffic-shifting/)?

I will appreciate any response,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Serverless Framework doesn't have the support for it. However it is also not difficult to implement the support, so hopefully it will come quite soon.

Comment: Nice, any pointers on building the support (very new to serverless)? Does serverless converts serverless.yml to SAM (SAM provides the canary support according to the link i shared)?

Comment: No, it converts yml to cloudformation stack. Take a look at recent pull requests which implement similar features, like env vars, and see that in the end it's just: parse yml and map to cloudformation json

Answer (score 1):

Right now? No, but AWS recently announced support for it:

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-lambda-supports-traffic-shifting-and-phased-deployments-with-aws-codedeploy/
- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-canary-release-deployments/

If you want to see this feature in sls, [create an issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues) and track its progress.